# soap enumeration value in php

Tags: php, soap, enumeration

I want to create a soap enumeration value in php. Here is the complex object type customer and CustomerStage

```
<complexType name="Customer">
<complexContent>
<extension base="platformCore:Record">
<sequence>
<element name="customForm" type="platformCore:RecordRef" minOccurs="0"/>
<element name="entityId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
***<element name="stage" type="listRelTyp:CustomerStage" minOccurs="0"/>***
</sequence>
<!-- primary record internalId -->
<attribute name="internalId" type="xsd:string"/>
<attribute name="externalId" type="xsd:string"/>
</extension>
</complexContent>
</complexType>


<simpleType name="CustomerStage">
<restriction base="xsd:string">
<enumeration value="_customer"/>
<enumeration value="_lead"/>
<enumeration value="_prospect"/>
</restriction>
</simpleType>
```

I am not sure how to create a customer by assigning a stage to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can create a customer either, since, if I'm reading your complex type correctly, you only have `listRelTyp` as an option. I always get a bit dizzy when looking at raw WSDL files, but on first look, I think this is just for generating a list of customers not for creating new customers.

Are you using the SOAPClient class in PHP? If so, can do `__getTypes` and `__getFunctions`, and it will show a slightly more readable list than what you have.

Comment: Here is the link to wsdl https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2009_2_0/netsuite.wsdl